# What should be the workerThread pool size for spring webflux applications?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

My requirement is to have other Java applications running on the same server on which spring webflux application is to deployed . As spring webflux uses as many worker threads as CPU cores by default  , wont these cause CPU contention problems for other Java applications ? Should i decrease the number of worker threads for better performance of all applications ?

Answer (score 1):

Tuning this on a shared server with multiple running application is a bit counter productive e.g. what if one of the applications experiences a spike in CPU utilization? In this case you would have to choose between:

1. Sharing CPU cores between all applications. This will lead to possible contention but it will also utilize all available CPU cores.
2. Assigning CPU cores to specific applications and risking under utilization. This is also a more complex setup that probably will have to be done on the OS level and will differ between Windows and Linux.

Which route you choose depends on what type of application you have e.g. do you optimize for throughout, latency or maximum GC pause. There is no one answer that will fit all here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a doubt, If I reduce the number of worker threads to say 4 on a 24 core server ,it would reduce the contention problem to a great extent. Do you think the same ?

Comment: Only if you ensure that given CPU cores are assigned to your application. Normally the cores are shared between all processes running in the system so even if you reduce to 4 these 4 cores still would be shared on OS level.